# why yargs.argv causes handler function to invoke

Tags: javascript, node.js, args, yargs

```
const yargs = require("yargs");

yargs.version = "1.0.0";

yargs.command({
  command: "add",
  describe: "do addition ",
  handler: function () {
    console.log("addition complete");
  },
}).argv;
```

In the above code using yargs i was trying to create a command **add**
and on running the script with `node . add` the handler function is executed and i get the the expected output

> $ node . add
> addition complete

but when the same code is run without the **.argv** the output is blank and the handler function is not executed .
in the docs it is not stated what ***.argv*** is , weather its an object or a function and how it actually works . at first glance it looks like a normal method invocation but

When you do the following
`console.log(typeof yargs.argv);`

The output is

> $ node . add
> addition complete
> object

If ***yargs.argv*** is an like any other Object then just by accessing it how and why it is able to invoke a function

can somebody explain whats actually happening and where am i missing out .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yargs is using a [`#getter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get), this allows javascript to call a function when a property is called.

Example:

```js
const obj = {
  log: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  get latest() {
    if (this.log.length === 0) {
      return undefined;
    }
    return this.log[this.log.length - 1];
  }
};

console.log(obj.latest);
// expected output: "c"
```

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/yargs/yargs/blob/master/lib/yargs-factory.ts) you can see when you call `.argv`, yargs just calls `.parse()`:

```js
 const yargs = new YargsInstance(processArgs, cwd, parentRequire, _shim);
 // Legacy yargs.argv interface, it's recommended that you use .parse().
 Object.defineProperty(yargs, 'argv', {
     get: () => {
        return yargs.parse();
      },
     enumerable: true,
});
```